# Show a limit of piecewise function does not exist as x tends to 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I am given a function, f(x), as follows:

f(x)=sin(1/x) if $0<x\leq1$ and f(x)=4 if x=0.

clearly this is an example of a function integrable on [0,1] but it is discontinuous at x=0.  How would you show that the limit of the unction does not exist as x tends to 0?

So I know that a limit exists if the right and left limits are the same but it does not work in the case of sin(1/x) in which x=0 leads to an undefined function.  How might I do that rigorously.  I already looked at the definition of continuous functions and tried using that but does that mean I have to do it twice for each function?

Comment: just as a notice, the "piecewise" part here is irrelevant, since the limit ignores the only value where it has a different definition.  (We explicitly do not look at x=0 when evaluating the limit as x approaches 0)

Answer (score 1):

If we draw a picture, everything is clear: near $0$, $\sin(1/x)$ wiggles desperately between $-1$ and $1$.

If we want to be formal, we can use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit. Suppose that the limit exists and is equal to $a$. Then for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is a $\delta$ such that if $0\lt |x-0|\lt \delta$ then $|\sin(1/x)-a|\lt \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{10}$, and suppose that $\delta$ "works" for this $\epsilon$. Note that there exists $x$ such that $|x-0|\lt \delta$ and $\sin(1/x)=0$. Just pick $x=n\pi$ for large enough $n$. So $|0-a|\lt 1/10$.

Similarly, there exists $x$ such that $|x-0|\lt \delta$ and $\sin(1/x)=1$. Just pick $x=(2n+1/2)\pi$ for large enough $n$. Thus $|1-a|\lt 1/10$.

Now we have reached a contradiction. There is no $a$ such that simultaneously $|0-a|\lt 1/10$ and $|1-a|\lt 1/10$. If we want to be formal about proving this, we can use the Triangle Inequality.

Comment: Can you explain why you are picking x=n$\pi$ and x=(2n+1/2)$\pi$?  Why does there need to be 0 and 1 to show a contradiction here?

Comment: Can you explain also how you go from picking an $\n pi$ as x to concluding that |0-a|<$\epsilon$?

Comment: It doesn't have to be $0$ and $1$, it could be (depending on what $\epsilon$ is used to eet a contradiction) any two value taken on by $\sin x$, best is $-1$ and $1$, but $o$ and $1/2$ is fine. The point is that $\sin(1/x)$ takes on wildly different values for $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$, which is "why" it does not have a limit as $x\to 0$. About your second question, we know that if the limit $a$ exists, there is a $\delta$ such that $|\sin(1/x)-a|\lt \epsilon=1/10$ **whenever** $0\lt |x-0|\lt \delta$. But within $\delta$ of $0$, we can find an $x=1/(n\pi)$ (Cont)

Comment: (Cont)  and there $\sin(1/x)= 0$. That implies that $a$ must e close to $0$ (within $1/10$ of it. Working with large $(2n+1/2)\pi$ we find that the supposed limit $a$ must also be close to $1$. One cannot be simultaneously within $1/10$ of $0$ and $1/10$ of $1$. Hence there is no number $a$ that will qualify as a limit of $\sin(1/x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit exists then for all $x_n \rightarrow 0$ it must be that $f(x_n) \rightarrow c$
where $c$ is the limit. But for every number $r$ in $[-1,1]$ you can find a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) \rightarrow r$. Indeed if sin(y)=r. Then consider the sequence 
$x_n = \frac{1}{y+2\pi n}$ so that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ but $sin(\frac{1}{x_n})=r$